# how to write a generic SQL select statement to select a person who belong to all city

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have to write a generic sql query for following situation:

```
city_id, person_id
0           0
1           1
0           2
1           3
0           3
0           4
1           4
1           5
0           6
0           7
```

I have to select only those persons who belongs to both cities 0 and 1, if new city and new person will enter then select only those person how belong to all city.

Comment: You should choose the database you are using and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: have you actually tried to figure this out yourself? if so, show us your attempts at a solution so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To find people belonging to both City 0 and City 1, if those are the only two cities you're looking at:

```
SELECT person_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will show you all the `person_id` values that have more than one record (such as where they belong to more than one city.)

You can further refine this by city if you have more than two cities:

```
SELECT person_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE city_id IN (0, 1) -- or any city configuration you need.
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for hint, appreciated +1

Comment: If you have other city_id values in the database this won't quite match your requirement to match only 0 and 1.

Comment: @shawnt00 this is true. Like I said though it can be further defined through a `WHERE` clause. I'll add an edit.

Comment: I realize that. But the greater than test is another part of the problem when multiples cities are present. I doubt there are any duplicate rows in this problem so I won't fuss about distinct vs non-distinct. But I think that not testing for equality only adds more potential for a bug down the road and obscures the real intention anyway.

Comment: It could, although if the need becomes to see how many person_id's belong to more than one city (regardless of what it is) this will still work. It gives some flexibility. You are correct about duplicates, and that would be a problem to be aware of. However using distinct to weed out duplicates would require further constraint over which record to choose.

Answer (score 1):

something like following:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM table 
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > (
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) FROM table
  )-1);
```

I hope it helps others.

Comment: Why not `HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) FROM table
  ));`?

Comment: Why the -1? I don't quite understand that

Comment: in current situation this "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) FROM table" query return 2 and we are comparing  with ">" so we need 1, so "2 - 1 = 1" and if city will increase so 3-1, 4-1 so on ... and if you compare with "=" then you don't need to minus (-)

Comment: So the only way it could be strictly great is to have exactly one more than one few, which is all of them.

Comment: We're assuming that (person_id, city_id) pairs are unique in this table. They probably are but I would note that as a caveat to the `count(*)`. Otherwise why not just say `count(*) = (select count(distinct) ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

This query doesn't make any assumption about how many cities are in the database.

```
select person_id from T
where city_id in (0, 1)
group by person_id
having count(distinct city_id) = 2 /* distinct isn't necessary if city_id is guaranteed unique per person */
```

Comment: This is not a generic solution, if city will increase then you have to change this.

Comment: I took this pair of cities as special. If he needs to match an ever increased number of cites then naturally the constant 2 will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 0):

If your city_id is auto increment. Something like this would work too.

```
SELECT person_id
FROM table 
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT MAX(city_id) FROM cities)+1;
```

Comment: What if the question is to find the persons belonging to cities 0 and 3?